# How to check programmatically whether WiFi adb is connected or disconnected in android?

Tags: android, adb, android-wifi

I am using WiFi adb to run apps. 
I want to know if adb is connected or disconnected in my activity.
I don't want to go to the adb app to check if adb connected or disconnected.

Can you suggest some programmatic solution for this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the state of port 5555 (or other port you have defined) using `netstat`. If ADB over Wifi is on, the state of port will be LISTEN.